# How to handle an ALTER TABLE RENAME?

Tags: postgresql, ddl, postgresql-9.5, event-triggers

Asuming I have a table **myTable** that stores:

```
  id   |   tableName
 ---------------------
   1   |     a
   2   |     b
  ...  |    ...
```

I have event triggers for **CREATE TABLE / DROP TABLE** events that updates the table "myTable".
Now I want to handle **`table renames`** to have a "right" reference in "myTable" when a table is renamed. I have tried listening for **ddl_command_end** event but I need to access to the original table name.

According to the docs :

```
pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
```

> **command**   pg_ddl_command  A complete representation of the command, in
>   internal format. This cannot be output directly, but it can be passed
>   to other functions to obtain different pieces of information about the
>   command.

But there's no link showing functions to extract the pieces I need.

How can this be done?

Comment: Additionally to the `tableName` you can store its ID: `objid` field. Using it you will be able to find the previous table name.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very very much!! =)

Comment: BTW what's your task? Probably the desired data already exists somewhere in the PostgreSQL information schema.

Comment: You can too use SELECT current_query() on event trigger for get the initial command SQL and detect the presence of  RENAME